# How to create uneven range number random function?

Tags: java, algorithm, random

We know that the classic range random function is like this:

```
public static final int random(final int min, final int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return min + rand.nextInt(max - min + 1);  // +1 for including the max
}
```

I want to create algorithm function for generating number randomly at range between 1..10, but with uneven possibilities like:
1) 1,2,3   -> 3/6 (1/2)
2) 4,5,6,7 -> 1/6
3) 8,9,10  -> 2/6 (1/3)

Above means the function has 1/2 chance to return number between 1 and 3, 1/6 chance to return number between 4 and 7, and 1/3 chance to return number between 8 and 10.

Anyone know the algorithm?

**UPDATE:**
Actually the range between 1..10 is just served as an example. The function that I want to create would apply for any range of numbers, such as: 1..10000, but the rule is still same: 3/6 for top range (30% portion), 1/6 for middle range (next 40% portion), and 2/6 for bottom range (last 30% portion).

Comment: another very similar question on SO. Feel free to search....

Comment: @suud: What would the ranges look like for different sizes?

Comment: @MarceloCantos: for example if the range is between 1 and 10000 (1,2,3,...,9998,9999,10000). The range 1-3000 would have 3/6 chance, range 3001-7000 would have 1/6 chance, and range 7001-10000 would have 2/6 chance.

Comment: @MitchWheat If you believe it's a duplicate, there's a 'close' link below the question, where you can specify which question it's a duplicate of. You'd be doing a service to the SO community if you did so.

Comment: @Nick: meh! You do it! :)  I've done this many times. Only fair I let someone else have a go.

Comment: @MitchWheat So you're trolling, basically.

Comment: I think mitch is not wrong. You can find them with keywords "weight range random" although the rule is not same with mine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the algorithm:

```
int temp = random(0,5);
if (temp <= 2) {
  return random(1,3);
} else if (temp <= 3) {
 return random(4,7);
} else  {
 return random(8,10);
}
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT: As requested in your comment:

```
int first_lo = 1, first_hi = 3000; // 1/2 chance to choose a number in [first_lo, first_hi]
int second_lo = 3001, second_hi = 7000; // 1/6 chance to choose a number in [second_lo, second_hi] 
int third_lo = 7001, third_hi = 10000;// 1/3 chance to choose a number in [third_lo, third_hi] 
int second
int temp = random(0,5);
if (temp <= 2) {
  return random(first_lo,first_hi);
} else if (temp <= 3) {
 return random(second_lo,second_hi);
} else  {
 return random(third_lo,third_hi);
}
```

Comment: Hi, how about if the range is between 1 and 10000 or any other range number?

Comment: please give an example on what do you mean

Comment: Could you modify your algorithm so it can receive any input number for the min and max instead of using defined number? So that means the algorithm will be input-dependent (I hope the term is correct lol)

Comment: @sud the min and max will be limits for the range of generated numbers, right? I was asking about how would you pass the uneven probability for each of these numbers. Please give example input for a given range of numbers.

Comment: Yes. For example of the range: if the inputed range is between 1 and 10000 (1,2,3,...,9998,9999,10000). The number from range 1-3000 would have 3/6 chance, range 3001-7000 would have 1/6 chance, and range 7001-10000 would have 2/6 chance to occur.

Comment: @suud I have updated my response with as general solution as possible for the problem stated. If you specify the input better I can try to give a better solution closer to what you want.

Comment: lol, although it's correct, it seems you don't get what I mean. The thing is the treshold number: 3000, 3001, 7000, etc shouldn't be hardcoded. They should be dynamic and dependant on the input. Imagine, you only have this skeleton function: public static int weightedRangeRandom(int min, int max) { //your code here }. User can input any value for the min & max. If user inputs 78934 as the max value, then the treshold numbers would be different, right?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, I think we can add one more parameter: "float[] weights" to the function. The weights contains float values that all must can be summed into 1.0 (else throw exception probably). For my case, the weights should contain values: 0.5f, 1/6, 1/3, respectively. The challenge is how to get the "5" from: "int temp = random(0,5)"; I have thought something, but maybe you have better idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10580/discussion-between-izomorphius-and-suud)

Answer (score 3):

You can fill an array of the desired numbers with the desired density, and then generate a random index and take the corresponding element. I think it is faster a bit, but propably it is not so important. Something like that, it's not the correct solution, just an example:

```
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6 ...
```

Or you can define domains first with if statements, and then generate a simple number from that domain.

```
int x = random(1,6)
if (x < 4) return random(1, 3);
if (x < 5) return random(4, 7);
return random(8, 10);
```

Comment: Except that the array is wrong for the desired density. See Marcelo's answer for the correct array.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is an example of what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Roll a 72-sided die to choose from the following array:

```
// Each row represents 1/6 of the space
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7,
 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9,
 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more? I'm a bit confused. What can I understand from your arrays, the number '1' has 12/72 (1/6) chance. But from my rule above, number '1' should has 3/6 (1/2) chance.

Comment: @sud: My reading of your question is that you want there to be a 3/6 probability of selecting a number from the first set. Since the set has three elements, the chance of selecting any given number from that set should be one third of that, i.e., 1/6. If there was a 1/2 probability of selecting a 1, and likewise a 1/2 probability of a 2 and 1/2 probability of a 3, then the probability of picking a number from the first set would be greater than one, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

```
final int lut[] = [
  1, 1, 1,
  2, 2, 2,
  3, 3, 3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8, 8,
  9, 9,
  10, 10
];

int uneven_random = lut[random.nextInt(lut.length)];
```

Or something along those lines...

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you're using whole numbers:

You need to use the following function:

```
f : A -> B
```

B = [b0, b1] represents the range of values you want from your random number generator

A = [b0, 2 * b1] so that the last branch of f actually reaches b1

```
f(x) = step((x / 3) , 
    f(x) is part of interval [b0, length(B)/3]
f(x) = step(x)  + E,   
    f(x) is part of interval [length(B) / 3, 2 * length(B) / 3],
    E is a constant that makes sure the function is continuous
f(x) = step(x / 2) + F,   
    f(x) is part of interval [2 * length(B) / 3, length(B)]
    F is a constant that makes sure the function is continuous
```

Explanation: it will take 3 times more numbers to get the same value on the first branch than it would on the second. So the probability to get a number on the first branch is 3 times than on the second, with values evenly distributed from a random number generator. The same applies for the 3rd branch.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: modified the intervals, you have to tweak it a bit but this is my general idea.

Comment: you might need to tweak the intervals though

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is my code (based on izomorphius's code) that hopefully solve my problem:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

public static int rangeRandom(final int min, final int max) {
    return min + rand.nextInt(max - min + 1);  // +1 for including the max
}

/**
 * 
 * @param min           The minimum range number
 * @param max           The maximum range number
 * @param weights       Array containing distributed weight values. The sum of values must be 1.0 
 * @param chances       Array containing distributed chance values. The array length must be same with weights and the sum of values must be 1.0 
 * @return              Random number
 * @throws Exception    Probably should create own exception, but I use default Exception for simplicity
 */
public static int weightedRangeRandom(final int min, final int max, final float[] weights, final float[] chances) throws Exception {
    // some validations
    if (weights.length != chances.length) {
        throw new Exception("Length of weight & chance must be equal");
    }

    int len = weights.length;

    float sumWeight = 0, sumChance = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        sumWeight += weights[i];
        sumChance += chances[i];
    }
    if (sumWeight != 1.0 || sumChance != 1.0) {
        throw new Exception("Sum of weight/chance must be 1.0");
    }

    // find the random number
    int tMin = min, tMax;
    int rangeLen = max - min + 1;

    double n = Math.random();
    float c = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        if (i != (len-1)) {
            tMax = tMin + Math.round(weights[i] * rangeLen) - 1;
        }
        else {
            tMax = max;
        }

        c += chances[i];
        if (n < c) {
            return rangeRandom(tMin, tMax);
        }
        tMin = tMax + 1;
    }

    throw new Exception("You shouldn't end up here, something got to be wrong!");
}
```

Usage example:

```
int result = weightedRangeRandom(1, 10, new float[] {0.3f, 0.4f, 0.3f}, 
    new float[] {1f/2, 1f/6, 1f/3});
```

The code might still has an inaccuracy in distributing the subrange boundaries (tMin & tMax) because of division by weight resulted in decimal value. But it's unavoidable I guess, because the range numbers are integers.

Some input validations might be required, but I left out for sake of simplicity.

Critics, corrections and reviews are gratefully welcomed :)

Comment: Hi could you please explain why there are two float arrays one for weight and the other for chance?