# How to change probability of random numbers

Tags: java, random

First of all, I did a search on this topic but I could not found anything similar to what I'm trying to accomplished, so this could be a duplicate question.

I would like to have a function that returns a number (1 or 2) with a probability of 0.8% for the number one and 0.2% for the number two.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create uneven range number random function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330517/how-to-create-uneven-range-number-random-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0 and 1.  If the number is between 0 and 0.8, return 1.  else, return 2:

```
return rnd.nextFloat() < 0.8 ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and concise

Answer (score 0):

You just make intervals, and if your random number fits in the interval, you have a hit. In this most simple example, you make intervals 1-4 and 5. So you fetch random number from 1 to 5. if it's a 1-4 (80% probability) you act as it's 1, and if it's 5 (20% probability) you act as it's 2.

Answer (score 0):

For example, make an array of 100 numbers. 20 numbers with number two, and 80 numbers with number one.

Use the Random class to generate a number between 0 and 100. Then you use that number to get the result from the array.

This is just an example, you can use another values in the array.